# Raw Input keyboard with RIDEV_NOHOTKEYS causes weird behavior

Tags: windows, winapi, raw-input

When I register a Raw Input keyboard device and set the RIDEV_NOHOTKEYS flag, like this:

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE device = {};
device.usUsagePage = 0x01;
device.usUsage = 0x06;
device.dwFlags = RIDEV_NOHOTKEYS;
device.hwndTarget = hwnd;
```

While my window has focus, the left and right windows keys stop working (they don't bring up the start menu). All other hotkeys I can think of still work. Alt-tab works, but it doesn't bring up the "fancy" alt-tab menu with thumbnails, but the old classic menu with icons:

[image: classic alt-tab menu]

There is nothing unusual happening in WM_INPUT message processing; I look at the structures, and call DefWindowProc at the end. I also don't have any keyboard hooks installed, or any other form of input.

According to the documentation, RIDEV_NOHOTKEYS should only affect application-defined hotkeys. This happens even when I don't register any hotkeys myself, so there are no application-defined hotkeys, unless Windows itself registers some (but then, why are they not system hotkeys?).

Does anyone have some experience with this or some explanation why this is happening, and suggestions how to prevent it? (This is on Windows 10, version 1803)

Comment: I can confirm the issue on Windows 8.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue on Windows 10 1903.